# (google map) Could not start ionic app

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework, npm

i have some issue.
could not start ionic app when after installed google map plugin.
but if uninstalled google map plugin then can start app.
reason is why? i don't know.. please help me sir.

> ionic info

```
 @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
  ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v6.9.5
npm  : 3.10.10
OS   : Windows 7
```

> installed plugin version

```
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.2.9 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
```

Is there a google map plugin version for Android platform version 6.4.0? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself. 
remove cordova google-maps plugin (Version 2.2.9)
and
install cordova google-maps plugin (Version 2.2.8)